# How to use X-MC-MergeVars for handlebars

Tags: smtp, handlebars.js, mandrill

I am new to mandrill and trying to setup a mail using handlebars and SMTP. My template looks like -

```
<span> {{userName}}, </span> Welcome to ......
```

This is what my mailer.js looks like (running on node.js)

```
var mailer   = require("mailer")
  , username = "**@***.com"
  , password = "*********";

mailer.send(
  {host:           "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
   port:           25,
   to:             "**@gmail.com",
   from:           "**@gmail.com",
   subject:        "Mail using Mandrill!",
   authentication: "login",
   username:       "**@**.com",
   password:       "********",
   headers: {
      "X-MC-Track": "clicks",
      "X-MC-Autotext": true,
      "X-MC-Template": "newsFeed",
      "X-MC-MergeVars": {"userName": "Pranav"},
      "X-MC-MergeLanguage": "handlebars"
   }
  }, function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```

I receive mail, but userName is not replaced with the userName value passed with X-MC-MergeVars and is replaced with empty string.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

All of your mail headers need to be strings; you're currently passing a JavaScript object for the mergevars.

Try using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the object to a string for the header:

```
  "X-MC-MergeVars": JSON.stringify( {"userName": "Pranav"} ),
```